# JQUERY if string contains two words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to find the answer out there for this one.

I have users filling out a form to enter their name for a ticket. This is done with one field for the whole name. Now it's important I check for both second and first names.

Everything is working perfectly. But for the life of me I can't seem to work out a new Elseif statement to check that the var contains TWO words.

Any tips?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user_details_form_button').live('click', function(){
        var check_name_b = '';
        var check_email_b = '';
        var check_phone_b = '';
        proceed = true;
        window.location.hash = 'tickethash';
        $('.userinput_name_b').each(function(){

            check_name_b = $(this).val();
            if(check_name_b == ''){ 
                $(this).css('border-color','#FF0000'); 
                $(this).attr("placeholder", "*Full Name Required");
                proceed = false;
            }else{
                if(check_name_b.replace(/ /g,'').length < 5){
                    $(this).css('border-color','#FF0000');
                    $(this).attr("placeholder", "*Full Name Required");
                    $(this).val("");
                    proceed = false;
                }else if(check_name_b.length > 40){
                    $(this).css('border-color','#FF0000');
                    $(this).attr("placeholder", "*Full Name Required");
                    $(this).val("");
                    proceed = false;
                }else{
                    $(this).css('border-color','#CCCCCC'); 
                }  
            }

        });
```

Comment: i would suggest not only checking for 2 words as some spanish people for exmaple have names like: "Carlos Botega dos Ditos".

Comment: Also, `live` has been deprecated for a while now. Use `on` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` to do this for you...

```
var check_name_b = $(this).val().trim().split(" ");
if (check_name_b.length < 2) {
    // no space in name, therefore it's only one word (or none!)
}
```

However, I'd strongly recommend using 2 fields for first name and surname.  Not only is this what people will expect, being used to seeing it on nearly all other websites, it's more robust and easier to handle input.  What happens if I put "Mr Archer"?  That's not my full name, but it's 2 words.

Comment: Yes, I think you probably have a valid point. Seems like I'm trying to fight a losing battle doing things this way. I will consider your propasal!

Comment: I've updated it slightly to now trim the string value before splitting it.  As pointed out by @lolka_bolka below, it would have accepted just a bunch of spaces with nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regular expression:

```
if (!check_name_b.match(/^[a-z\.]+ [a-z]+/i)) {
    alert('Invalid name');
}
```

Do not use `split`, like others says, because if I am just typed some spaces, then that will success also.

Comment: Sorry to be noob, but exactly how would I implement this? else if (str.indexOf(/^[a-z\.]+ [a-z]+/i) >= 2) ???

Answer (score 1):

Check with this:

`$(this).val().split(" ").size() > 1`

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is working perfectly. But for the life of me I can't seem to work out a new Elseif statement to check that the var contains TWO words.

Two word mean, that there is a space between them.

Try the `.split()` function from jQuery.

Like:

```
words = input.split(' ');
if(words.length >= 2) {
  //do something
}
```